# Immense error in regression exercise

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, linear-regression

I am currently trying to understand how to solve regression problems with the help of Tensorflow. Unfortunately, as soon as I try to introduce a second dimension for my input-data, the error or loss gets insanely large.

The dataset I am using is self-made and quite simple. The values are all sorted and X2 is just every value from x1 + 1

```
X1 = [2.167,3.1,3.3,4.168,4.4,5.313,5.5,5.654,6.182,6.71,6.93,7.042,7.59,7.997,9.27,9.779,10.791]
X2 = [3.167,4.1,4.3,5.168,5.4,6.313,6.5,6.654,7.182,7.71,7.93,8.042,8.59,8.997,10.27,10.779,11.791]
y = [1.221,1.3,1.573,1.65,1.694,1.7,2.09,2.42,2.53,2.596,2.76,2.827,2.904,2.94,3.19,3.366,3.465]
```

I tried to approximate the values using linear regression:

```
numbers = pd.DataFrame({'x1': X1, 'x2':X2})

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(numbers,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=101)

X_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,2], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32)

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2,1])) 
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1]))

final_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(X_data, w1), b1)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(final_output-y_target))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

steps = 5000

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(steps):

        sess.run(train,feed_dict={X_data:X_train,y_target:y_train})

        # PRINT OUT A MESSAGE EVERY 100 STEPS
        if i%500 == 0:

            print('Currently on step {}'.format(i))

            training_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X_data:X_test,y_target:y_test})
            print("Training cost=", training_cost/5)

    training_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X_data:X_test,y_target:y_test})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost)
```

This gives me the output

```
Currently on step 0
Training cost= 12376958566.4
Currently on step 500
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 1000
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 1500
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 2000
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 2500
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 3000
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 3500
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 4000
Training cost= nan
Currently on step 4500
Training cost= nan
Training cost= nan
```

I received a little better results with the Adagrad optimizer which gave me an error of 5, but I still think there should be a lot more possible.

Would it maybe be an option here to add a hidden layer? I tried also this previously, but while using relu as my activation function in the layer and just `f(x)=x` on my output layer, I received similar high nan-errors.

Comment: It seems to be a problem of learning rate. Try `optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=5e-5)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.  First, you're using `tf.reduce_sum` instead of `tf.reduce_mean`, so the more data you have, the bigger your loss.  This sends a huge signal to the `GradientDescentOptimizer`, so the learned weights make a huge jump, and your model diverges.

The second issue is that your learning rate is still too big; as user2015762 suggests, this is often the problem when you have an increasing loss.  I got good results using `learning_rate=0.001` with your code.